# Remove NA Values in rhandsontable heatmap

Tags: r, shiny, heatmap, rhandsontable

I'd like to have all but the NA values display color using rhandsontable. So, for example, if you ran the following code in the R console with rhandsontable installed, the first column would be grey because rhandsontable can't deal with the NA and the numeric values, I believe. But, if you remove the one NA, making the cell blank, the rest of the cells regain their color.

```
> MAT = matrix(rnorm(50), nrow = 10, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:10],
+                                                    letters[1:5]))
> MAT[1,1] <- NA
> rhandsontable(MAT) %>% hot_heatmap()
```

In my actual dataset, I have a lot of NA values and I don't want each of those columns to appear grey. How do I tell rhandsontable to only grey out the NA values, and not the rest in the column?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack...

I replaced NA values with a very specific 0.001.

And then I tweaked the renderer such that it colors cells with 0.001 light grey:

```
# Used by hot_heatmap
renderer_heatmap = function(color_scale) {
  renderer = gsub("\n", "", "
                  function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                  heatmapScale  = chroma.scale(['%s1', '%s2']);
                  if (instance.heatmap[col]) {
                    mn = instance.heatmap[col].min;
                    mx = instance.heatmap[col].max;
                    pt = (parseInt(value, 10) - mn) / (mx - mn);
                    if (value == 0.001) {
                      td.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
                    } else {
                      td.style.backgroundColor = heatmapScale(pt).hex();
                    }
                  }
                  }
                  ")
  renderer = gsub("%s1", color_scale[1], renderer)
  renderer = gsub("%s2", color_scale[2], renderer)
  renderer
}
```

Not my finest hour, and would welcome better answers!

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but anyway.. The modern versions of `rhandsontable` (I have 0.3.7) deal with NAs properly by displaying those cells as grey without affecting colors of the other cells.